# Stripe переход с годовой на месячную подписку

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, stripe, stripe-payments

Переход с годовой на месячную подписку должен применится в конце годовой подписки а не сразу,есть способ реализовать через schedule stripe,но тогда управлени.
Через базу,используя задание, делать не особо хочется, как то не надёжно.
Не нравится что управление переходит в scheduler id. Дальше допилить логику к примеру для отмены подписки и т.д.
Кто как справлялся?

Comment: У вас есть дата окончания оплаченной подписки и тип подписки, 2 независимых сущности. Переход с одного на другое - просто смена типа следующей предлагаемой, и больше ничего. Вообще не понимаю, где тут проблема и при чем тут планировщики. Введите юзеру настройку "тип предпочитаемой подписки", и на основе этой настройки предлагайте следующее списание.

Comment: @aepot ,если на годовой он отменил через 6 месяцев,6 месяцев он еще пользуется годовой подпиской, по истечение годовой переходит на подписку месячную. Как это сделать через апи страйпа?

Comment: @aepot
Пока нашел два варианта, первый создаваю новую подписку через триал по вермени окончание прошлой,лиюо через шедулер.